# Sony TV RCA output into Yamaha HS80M input via RCA male to XLR male: Is it safe?

Tags: cable, monitors, connectors

Title says it all really. Just want to check up before I do this.

I have a spare set of [Yamaha HS80M](http://usa.yamaha.com/products/music-production/speakers/hs_series/hs80m/?mode=model) monitors lying around. Rather than just having them sitting on the shelf, I'd like to connect them to a Sony LCD TV directly.

Is this safe? Is it advisable?

I plan to use a cable that looks something like this:

[image: RCA male to XLR male]

I realize the signal isn't balanced. I'm really most concerned as to whether this is in some way dangerous.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not dangerous at all. You may have impedance matching issues though. And possibly lots of noise in the signal because of the unbalanced source and mis-matched impedance.

Start with the volume on the Yamahas all the way down and, with something playing on the television, nudge the volume up ever so slightly until you can hear the source. You want to make certain a too-hot signal from the TV doesn't rip your speakers apart.

For best results a DI with properly matched inputs for the TV would be my advice. Something like [this](http://www.radialeng.com/re-proav1.htm) would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian. I've hooked them up (minus DI for now - cheers for the link) and things are fine. TV has never sounded so good! I'm surprised how little noise these cables are picking up. They are rather short and that's all I can put it down to.